# "./jfrog rt bs --rescan=true" Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -rescan

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

Need to rescan an already published build in Jfrog Artifactory.

I am overwriting the same build name and id with a new build, but when I scan it shows me the old scan report. Which is why I need the rescan option but it's giving me the error shown below.
What am I doing wrong here?
Is there any other way to rescan a published build?

Found "--rescan" here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Xray

```
./jfrog rt bs --rescan=true
```

> Error: Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -rescan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it on the latest version of the JFrog CLI? It appears that you are using an older version that doesn't support the "--rescan" flag.

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure what version we are using. I'll test this out.